# Connect to Bluetooth via MAC Address on iOS

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing a program that connects to a BLE device connected to an arduino. Is it possible, in iOS, to connect to a BLE device using a known MAC Address (so I can skip the discovery stage)? I didn't see any options for this in the developer guide and was hoping there was a way to pull this off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very short answer to the question: no